# Can someone help convert this asm code to c++ for x64?

Tags: c++, assembly

I am creating something but it using inline asm. I need to compile this in x64 so if someone could help convert this code to a c++ equivalent that would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
DWORD dwReturn;

__asm 
{
push dwReturn;
pushfd;
pushad;
};

__asm 
{
popad;
popfd;
ret;
}
```

Comment: I would say basically this pushes your variable and then returns. What's the point in this assembler code ? You wrote that it is you who created this. What is your goal ? Getting rid of the inline assembler ?

Comment: Yes this is not the full function only the asm part so it may not make much sense. This is not my function I didn't write it I just want to know if I could do the same thing this is doing but in c++ as I to compile my project in x64.

Answer (score 2):

Alas that cannot be done, your inline assembly does not code any algorithm that can be converted in an high level language. The instructions your are using are very architecture dependent and, of course, there is no support for that in C++.

I'm not aware of any compiler intrinsic that can perform a `pusha`, a `push` or a `pushf`.

Comment: Maybe `setjmp`/`longjmp`, depending on the use case.

Comment: @Jester yes, the `dwReturn` make it plausible. I don't really know if I should update the answer